# Appending to the middle of a line in a textfile sed

Tags: sed

I am completely new to sed script. I have been researching how to add text to a file and managed to get the text I want adding to the correct line in the file but can not find a way to add it to the correct position!

so the line I have in the text file looks like this

```
  listen_addresses = 'localhost, 192.0.0.0' # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

I want to add an IP so the line looks like:

```
   listen_addresses = 'localhost, 192.0.0.0, 192.0.0.0'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Through trial and error I only have:

```
   sed -i '/listen_addresses/ s/.*/&,192.0.0.0/' testfile
```

which gives:

```
  listen_addresses = 'localhost, 192.0.0.0' # what IP address(es) to listen on; 192.168.0.0
```

how do I go about adding it to the correct position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways. One of them could be to search for last `'` and use parentheses to save the data matched. I changed single quotes to double quotes because I want to match one of them inside the regular expression:

```
sed -i "/listen_addresses/ s/^\(.*\)\('\)/\1, 192.0.0.0\2/" testfile
```

- `^\(.*\)`: Matches from the beginning until end of line (greeding).
- `\('\)`: Backtrack from the end until a `'`. So it will match the last one in the string.
- `\1`: The content saved between first pair of parentheses.
- `, 192.0.0.0`: Literal string.
- `\2`: Content saved between second pair of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm completely new to sed and trying to learn, can I ask you to explain a bit more of your script? What is the \2/" for at the end?

Comment: @SarahAddis: Edited to add an explanation.

Comment: Sorry to comment again! I am using this command as part of a python SSH.execute command and while this works perfectly manually on the remote server is does not work as part of my script as it doesn't interept the \1 or \2 properly!! I've tried experimenting and using the other suggestion but it completely messes up the line in the file! Is there another way to save the content?

Comment: I know this is a python and not sed related problem I was just wondering if there was an easy way to edit the sed!

Comment: @SarahAddis: Sorry. I can't help with that. No idea about Python or SSH. Perhaps you could open a different question, because it doesn't seem to be related with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the `' #` part of the line:

```
sed -i "/listen_addresses/ s/' #/, 192.0.0.0' #/" testfile
```

Note that I used double quotes so the single quote can be easilly inserted.